# Creating a data frame with similar observations in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I create columns with similar observations? I want to create the following data frame with 30 rows, here is an example for 3 rows.

```
b =c (2018, 2018, 2018)
c=c(100,100,100)
d=c("AB", "AB", "AB")
de<-data.frame(b,c,d)
names(de)<-c("year","Pmax","province")
```

Comment: You can check `rep` or `replicate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, this code can help you. I create a dataframe with 30 similar rows.

```
b=rep(2018,30)
c=rep(100+0:9,each=3)
d=rep(paste0(LETTERS[1],LETTERS[2:11]),each=3)
de = data.frame(b,c,d)
names(de)<-c("year","Pmax","province")
head(de,9)
  year Pmax province
1 2018  100       AB
2 2018  100       AB
3 2018  100       AB
4 2018  101       AC
5 2018  101       AC
6 2018  101       AC
7 2018  102       AD
8 2018  102       AD
9 2018  102       AD
```